# Как создать WebDAV class 2 сервер

Tags: nginx, webdav

Как создать WebDAV class 2 сервер на основе nginx  или чего-то другого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось в Apache все давно есть. И на базе него можно спокойно создавать. Вот собственно [пример](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-webdav-access-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

согласно [rfc4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-18.2), «класс 2» означает (как минимум) поддержку *webdav*-метода *LOCK*.

согласно же документации к программе *nginx*, модуль *ngx_http_dav_module* поддерживает лишь *webdav*-методы [PUT, DELETE, MKCOL, COPY и MOVE](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_dav_module.html#dav_methods).

т.е., насколько я понимаю, для реализации «класса 2», требуется написать собственный модуль для программы *nginx*, который будет удовлетворять всем перечисленным в *rfc4918* требованиям. цитирую:

> A class 2 compliant resource MUST meet all class 1 requirements and
> support the LOCK method, the DAV:supportedlock property, the DAV:
> lockdiscovery property, the Time-Out response header and the Lock-
> Token request header.  A class 2 compliant resource SHOULD also
> support the Timeout request header and the 'owner' XML element.

> Class 2 compliant resources MUST return, at minimum, the values "1"
> and "2" in the DAV header on all responses to the OPTIONS method.

Comment: Это я в курсе. Я и спрашиваю - как создать его? Может есть какие-то наработки или реализации

Comment: есть, конечное наработки. тот же упомянутый модуль *ngx_http_dav_module* **уже** содержит всё необходимое. надо всего лишь добавить требуемой функциональности.

Comment: Ещё есть dav_ext в котором как раз и не хватает LOCK, UNLOCK